# Find what range a number belongs to

Tags: excel

Ive written a function to calculate what **MARK** a student gets, based on a scoring table.
Why does my function work only for A mark?

This what the excel sheet looks like

```
COLUMN:    A      B      C      
        Student  SCORE  MARK
    1    adsf     90     A
    2    asgfd    89     FALSE     

    3     A       90    100
    4     B       81    89
    5     C       71    80
    6     D       61    70
    7     E        56   60
    8     Fx       0    55
```

This is the function:

```
{=IF(B1>=$B$3:$B$8,IF(B1<=$C$3:$C$8,$A$3:$A$8))}
```

I'm using {} brackets for array functions. (CTRL SHIFT ENTER)

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track but your formula is returning an array not a single value. Wrapping the result in LOOKUP should give the desired result:

```
=LOOKUP("Z",IF(B1>=$B$3:$B$8,IF(B1<=$C$3:$C$8,$A$3:$A$8))
```

This returns the last matching grade since "Z" is larger than any other text value in the range.

A simpler method is:

```
=LOOKUP(-B1,-C$3:C$8,A$3:A$8)
```

The negative signs are needed so that the lookup values are in ascending order.

Comment: I like the negative option, deceptively simple!

Comment: @lori_m thank you. I still don't understand how he looks up a value if it's not in the list, and why those negative signs?

Comment: @myro: LOOKUP doesn't do an exact match, it finds the first value in the lookup range less than or equal to the lookup value and returns the corresponding value from the result range but the lookup range must be in ascending order, see MS help for further info. To simplify things, you might want to order the grade table in ascending order of marks and use column B as lookup range then you won't need the negative signs.